# Why cross section of $e^+ e^- \to \bar{q} q$ is 3 times larger than $e^+ e^- \to \mu^+ \mu^-$?

Tags: particle-physics, quantum-chromodynamics

I know the usual answer: quarks carry color charge (let us denote them r,g,b), antiquarks anti color charge, and since the initial state ($e^+ e^-$) does not carry any color charge (and color is always conserved), the only possibility is to pick-up $r\bar{r}$, $g \bar{g}$, or $b \bar{b}$, thus 3 possibilities more than for the production of di-muons.

Now, I'm not totally satisfied because: since my initial state was colorless, my final state must be a color singlet: $\psi_s = \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}(r\bar{r} + g \bar{g} + b \bar{b})$. Saying that $r \bar{r}$ is a color singlet (as suggested in my quick un-satifying answer) is not true: $r \bar{r}$ appears in the linear superposition of the color singlet, yes, but also in some linear superpositions of the color octet (since with group theory, $3 \otimes \bar{3} = 8 \oplus 1$).

So how can I get this famous factor 3 between the two cross-sections?

Comment: I am not sure why you are confused since you already have the answer. Color singlet is the same as colorless. OF course $r\bar{r}$ is colorless combination (multiply with phases and conjugate phases, they always cancel). Then, you have to think of the degrees of freedom you have. Out of $r,b,g, \bar{r}, \bar{b}, \bar{g}$ you can only make 3 colorless combinations.

Comment: @Marion: that might be surprising but $r \bar{r}$ is not necessarily colorless. This confusion is similar as saying that when you add two spin 1/2, the $S_z =0$ is spinless. As you know $s_z=0$ can come from the $S=1$ triplet or the spinless $S=0$.

Comment: But what you re saying is like "the atom is not really neutral because it is composed out of electrons and protons". The state $r\bar{r}$ is coloreless in the sense that if you rotate $r$ by some phase you rotate $\bar{r}$ by its conjugate which give you 1.

Comment: @Marion: I suppose you're referring to a rotation in the color space (if not I don't know what you're talking about). I agree, that if I rotate all my colors so that $r \to g \to b$ then indeed $\bar{r} \to \bar{g} \to \bar{b}$. The point is that if my initial $q\bar{q}$ pair was $r\bar{r}$, it will become $g\bar{g}$ => you change the state! In order to be a singlet and so invariant regardless of the rotation "angle", you need to be in the state $\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}(r\bar{r}+ g\bar{g} + b\bar{b})$.

Comment: I might have it confused in my mind as well but that state is actually the result of a scattering product. $q\bar{q}$ is indeed what you describe. Despite that, $r\bar{r}$ it self is colorless. Color rotation is not a $\mathbb{Z}_3$ rotation, it is a continuous one and as much as you rotate $r$ you anti-rotate $\bar{r}$ in the same amount resulting in no rotation.

Comment: @Marion: the color rotation I was talking about is the one due to the gauge symmetry namely: if my quark field $q$ is represented as a column of 3 Dirac fields $q_1,q_2,q_3$ where 1,2,3 corresponds to the 3 possible colors, the rotation applied on $q$ is done with a matrix $U$ of $SU(3)$ group, i.e. $U \propto e^{-\alpha_a \lambda^a}$ where $a$ ranges from 1 to 8 and $\lambda_a$ is a Gell-Man matrix, and $\alpha_a$ the 8 continuous angles of the rotation. Now I agree that a term in the Lagrangian $\bar{q} q$ is invariant with this rotation (because $U^\dagger U = 1$).

Comment: … but (continuing my previous comment), it does not mean that $\bar{r} r$ is a color singlet. It's a different thing ($\bar{q}$ is the Dirac adjoint field).

Comment: but the pion is then color charged? Your pion-like state $|\psi_s\rangle = |q\bar{q}>$ is colorless and as a result whatever superposition you make must inherit this and vice versa. If you make a rotation to $q$ you make an "anti-rotation" to $\bar{q}$ and this applies to the colors individually too!

Comment: as you said, the pion is colorless (singlet of color) meaning that what you write $|q\bar{q}>$ is actually $\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}(|q_r\bar{q_r}>+|q_g\bar{q_g}>+|q_b\bar{q_b}>)$ (well I should have written a tensorial product between the flavor state and color states). Hence, whatever rotation you make, the singlet remains a singlet (by definition of the singlet in the theory groups).

Comment: yes but you say that the individual $|q_r \bar{q}_r \rangle$ is not colorless, right? Can you give me some reference where this is mentioned?

Comment: Go to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gluon

Comment: Go to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gluon You see that $r\bar{r}$ is involved in both the gluon octet of colors (which carries some color numbers) and the singlet (which has no color number at all: colorless). Hence, $r\bar{r}$ is not clearly defined in terms of group representation. Again, it is the analogous of the $s_z =0$ which appears in both spin 1 triplet and spin 0 singlet. In other words, $r\bar{r}$ is a superposition of octet and singlet with the appropriate Clebsch-Gordan coefficients.

Comment: The Wiki article comes in no contradiction to what I am saying. "In words, if one could measure the color of the state, there would be equal probabilities of it being red-antired, blue-antiblue, or green-antigreen." In any case, it is obvious to me (I m much less certain after this discussion though) that color-anticolor is a singlet state. Any superposition of it is obviously a singlet state as well.

Comment: So would you logically conclude that there are 3 singlets: $r\bar{r}$, $g\bar{g}$, $b\bar{b}$? If yes, you must admit that this is in contradiction with theory groups since according to $3 \otimes \bar{3}= 8 \oplus 1$, there is only 1 singlet.

Comment: No, the scattering will produce 1 singlet made out of the superposition and there is no way to distinguish which colorless combination is made of. This is the reason you have three diagrams.  There is no way to determine colors, all you can "observe" is the singlet which is 1 (and you actually observe its decay products of course). But think about general Hilbert spaces and arrays within them. If you have a state $|AA'\rangle$ obeying some symmetry then "sub-states" like $|AA'\rangle = |aa' + bb' + cc' + \ldots \rangle$ must obey the same rules.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19899/discussion-between-paganini-and-marion).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The point is that when doing calculations in QCD we only need to calculate the hard process (producing e.g. the $ r \bar{r} $) since non-perturbative dynamics will, with 100% probability, produce color singlets out of the final states. It might provide move intuition to write the relevant Feynman diagrams (assuming e.g. a $Z$ mediator) that produce the full color singlet, $ \frac{1}{ \sqrt{3} } \left( \left|  r \bar{r} \right\rangle  + \left|  g \bar{g} \right\rangle  + \left|  b \bar{b} \right\rangle  \right) $,

[image]

The cross sections are only affected by the connected parts, since in non-perturbative QCD, it doesn't "cost" anything to pop $q \bar{q}$ pairs from the vacuum. Here we have 3 diagrams, and hence a factor of $3$.

One might be worried however, that the cross-sections are lowered since the hard $q\bar{q}$ pair might hadronize into two colorless pieces (e.g. two mesons). This is also occurs and all these possibilities need to be included to get the proper "factor of 3 boost".

Comment: hum, you seem to suggest that the color singlet is obtained thanks to the additional $q\bar{q}$ pair from the vacuum. But, even at the level of the hard process only, I thinks that the $q\bar{q}$ pair produced by the $e^+ e^-$ fusion must be in the color singlet state. In other words, if you were able to measure the color of this pair, you would find $r\bar{r}$ with a probability 1/3 and same for the 2 other colors. Am I wrong?

Comment: (continuing my previous comment): production of pairs of $q\bar{q}$ needs some energy (at least $2 m_q$). What's going on if you don't have this energy? That's why I'm saying that the original pair (connected to the $Z/gamma^*$ propagator) must be already in the singlet state.

Comment: I'm answering my own comment: if there is not enough energy to produce additional pair of quarks, there is still enough energy to produce massless gluons with the appropriate colors/anticolors to produce a singlet final state. Thank you JeffDror, for your answer which finally satisfies me.

Comment: @Paganini: I agree with what you write, but I just wanted to add that the $q\bar{q}$ produced in the hard process needs to be a colour singlet because the interaction with the $Z$ is colour diagonal (which in turn is because the $e+ e-$ are indeed also a colour singlet). I don't know if that was obvious to you or not.

Comment: since the hard process $q \bar{q}$ pair must be produced in the color singlet state, I'm back to my initial question: how from $\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}(r\bar{r}+g\bar{g}+b\bar{b})$ you get the famous factor 3 w.r.t the dimuons production??? In the diagram you gave above, the singlet was realized thanks to the hadronization, not at the initial $q\bar{q}$ pair.

Comment: I think I used sloppy language where I really shouldn't have. By "color singlet", I meant of opposite colours (which I agree is misleading phrasing), e.g., $r\bar{r} $. Other then this I'm not sure what is your confusion?

Comment: My confusion is related to this: being of opposite colors is not enough, my understanding is that the q$\bar{q}$ must be produced directly as a color singlet: $\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}(r\bar{r}+g\bar{g}+b\bar{b})$. And I don't succeed how to translate this with feynman diagrams. Just adding the 3 square amplitudes does not reflect this fact. It seems to me that adding the 3 amplitudes is better, but I must admit that I don't feel comfortable with this (as you said color can be considered as the spin).

Comment: The point is that the need to produce a color singlet is a "rule" for QCD due to its strong coupling at low energies. It is distinct from the  hard process which doesn't know anything about this rule. All the hard process demands is that the outgoing quark-antiquark are of opposite color (since in this case its made through a electroweak process). You can indeed get an outgoing colored particle out of the hard process, but since QCD increases in strength with distance these colored particles will quickly form colour singlets (i.e., mesons and baryons).

Answer (score 2):

I post a new version of my answer since I'm now convinced that my previous answer was clearly wrong. Looking at papers dealing with J/Psi ($c\bar{c}$ bound state) production at $e^+ e^-$ collider (see [1] for instance), the $q\bar{q}$ pair produced by the $e^+ e^-$ scattering can be either in the singlet state or the octet state. The singlet is $\psi_s = \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}(r\bar{r} + g\bar{g} + b\bar{b})$ while the 8 octets states are $\psi_{1…8}= r\bar{g}, g\bar{r}, r\bar{b}, b\bar{r}, g\bar{b}, b\bar{g}, \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(r\bar{r}-g\bar{g}), \frac{1}{\sqrt{6}}(r\bar{r}+g\bar{g}-2b\bar{b})$.
The $q\bar{q}$ pair must not carry hypercharge color number or isospin color number (but can however be member of octet). In other words it must be $r\bar{r}$ or $g\bar{g}$ or $b\bar{b}$. Hence, the total cross-section results from:

$$ \sigma = \Sigma_{c\bar{c} = r\bar{r}, g\bar{g}, b\bar{b}} ~~|\mathcal{M}|^2 ~~\left(|<\psi_s|c\bar{c}>|^2 + \Sigma_{a=1..8}|<\psi_a|c\bar{c}>|^2\right)$$

where $\mathcal{M}$ is the amplitude for the electroweak process (same as the one giving the di-muons neglecting masses and taking into account the electric charge of quarks). It gives:

$$ \sigma = |\mathcal{M}|^2 ~~\left(\Sigma_{c\bar{c} = r\bar{r}, g\bar{g}, b\bar{b}}|<\psi_s|c\bar{c}>|^2 + \Sigma_{c\bar{c} = r\bar{r}, g\bar{g}, b\bar{b}}\Sigma_{a=1..8}|<\psi_a|c\bar{c}>|^2\right) = |\mathcal{M}|^2 (1+2)$$

Hence the famous factor 3. As mentioned by JeffDror, if the $q\bar{q}$ is produced in the octet state, since the initial state $e^+ e^-$ is a singlet, during the hadronization of $q\bar{q}$, there will be emission of gluons/quark pair to produce a singlet final state.

[1] http://cds.cern.ch/record/256588/files/P00018653.pdf

Comment: I didn't downvote, but this is not correct since the 3 diagrams are distinct (they have different outgoing particles!). You can't just assume the amplitudes add coherently. You need to add the probabilities, not the amptlidues.

Comment: @JeffDror: how do you describe a diagram involving a linear superpositions of states (like the singlet)? I'm referring to the 3 diagrams corresponding only to the hard process namely 1) $e^+e^- \to r\bar{r}$, 2) $e^+e^- \to g\bar{g}$ and 3) $e^+e^- \to b\bar{b}$. You cannot know (even in theory) if the state was $r\bar{r}$, $g\bar{g}$ or $b\bar{b}$ (since singlet is a superposition of these 3 guys). That's why I would add the amplitudes not the square amplitude in this specific case.

Comment: But they are still considered distinguishable in the same way a spin up and a spin down electron are distinguishable. The reason we can't distinguish them is because of the theory happens to be strongly coupled, but this doesn't change the character of the particles. It just means that perturbation theory in the gauge coupling is no longer valid at finite order.

Comment: In the same way that even without spontneous symmetry breaking in the electroweak sector the up and down quarks would still be considered distinguishable.

Comment: Not sure if they are considered distinguishable. There is no way to know from an experiment if you produced red or greens or blues since they always come up in colorless states. You only know the possible degrees of freedom, in this case this is the 3 different in color else identical diagrams. You can just multiply by 3 straight away in this sense.